# How to get a string with the same value from within the hash and add it to an array ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I have the hashes:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "teste2"=>"2", "teste3"=>"3", "teste3m"=>"3m", "teste6"=>"6", "commit"=>"Search"}
```

Or:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "teste2m"=>"2m", "teste3"=>"3", "teste3m"=>"3m","teste4"=>"4", "teste7m"=>"7m", "commit"=>"Search"}
```

I want to get `teste` value and add in an array within a variable `x`

```
<%= x %>
```

When I print `x`, the output must be this:

```
["2","3","3m","6"]  
["2m","3","3m","4","7m" ]
```

Comment: `Hash#select` is what you are looking for. Something like `hash.select {|k,_| k[/\Ateste/] }.values `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
e = hash.select { |k, v| k.start_with?('teste') }.values
```

---

It looks like the hash is actually the `params`. If that is true you could do something like this:

```
# in the controller
@values = params.select { |k, v| k.start_with?('teste') }.values

# in the view
<%= @values.inspect %>
```

Comment: e = hash.select { |k, v| k.start_with?('teste') }.values <<< It worked. thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
hash = { 'tasty'=>'ice cream', 'tasteless'=>'D. Trump', 'taster'=>'good buds' }

hash.each_with_object([]) { |(k,v),a| a << v if k.start_with? 'taste' }
  #=> ["D. Trump", "good buds"]
```